# Problem in reading till EOF in python

Tags: python

i have a python code which should read in 2 integers from standard input till user presses Ctrl+D (i.e EOF)
  and do some processing .I tried the following code :
`n,k=map(int,[a for a in sys.stdin.read().split()])`
Here , when i enter two integers the programme accepts it and when i press Ctrl+D it shows the correct output , like:
`6 3`
but when i put in 2 pairs in intergers like:
`6 3
12 2` and then press Ctrl+D then instead of the desired result i get error that: 
[i]ValueError: Too many values to upack[/i]
So how do i correct the code for it to work properly?
I intend to have the shortest possible code for that
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x=map(int,[a for a in sys.stdin.read().split()])
2 3 4 5
>>> x
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and work against the list; this so you will accept a variable number of ints if required to do so

Comment: Why are you combining `map` with a pointless list comprehension? Use one or the other: `map(int, sys.stdin.read().split())` or `[int(a) for a in sys.stdin.read().split()]`

Comment: i'm not; i  used with fidelity whatever code was initially submitted and pointed out where the error was; the fact that there's a pointless list comprehension can be discussed after the initial problem is eliminated, you did it alright, cheers

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in how you read from stdin.  Entering `6 3` essentially makes your code equivalent to

```
n, k = [6, 3]
```

which will work fine.  Entering `6 3 12 2` though will result in

```
n, k = [6, 3, 12, 2]
```

which does not work, since you try to unpack a sequence of four values to only two targets.  If you want to ignore everything beyond the first two numbers, try

```
n, k = [int(a) for a in sys.stdin.read().split()][:2]
```

If you want to iterate through the numbers read from stdin in pairs, you can use

```
numbers = (int(a) for a in sys.stdin.read().split())
for n, k in zip(numbers, numbers):
    # whatever
```